# AVPlayer not showing startup spinner

Tags: swift, avplayer, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I am trying to play a remote mp4 video on tvOS in my application. There is a small problem, when i set the `AVPlayerViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame` then the spinner doesn't appear until the videos loads up. However, if I set `AVPlayerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1920.0, 1079.0)` it works perfectly fine. The spinner loads up in the start and then the video appears.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class PlayViewController : UIViewController {

    var avplayerVC : AVPlayerViewController?
    var videoUrlStr : String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("In PlayViewController View Did Load")

        avplayerVC = AVPlayerViewController()

        let avAsset = AVAsset(URL: NSURL.init(string: videoUrlStr!)!)
        let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
        avplayerVC?.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem)

        avplayerVC?.player?.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)

        avplayerVC?.player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: .New, context: nil)

        avplayerVC?.player?.play()
        print("Status 1: " +  "\(avplayerVC?.player?.status.rawValue)")

        print(self.view?.frame)

        // doesn't work
        //avplayerVC?.view.frame =  self.view.frame

        // doesn't work
        //avplayerVC?.view.frame =  CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1920.0, 1080.0)

        // works fine
        avplayerVC?.view.frame =  CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1920.0, 1079.0)
        self.view.addSubview((avplayerVC?.view!)!)
    }
}
```

I also tried to put log for `print(self.view?.frame)` in `viewDidLoad` and it prints out `(0.0 0.0; 1920.0,1080.0)`.

Comment: You could implement your own [Activity Indicator](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/index.html).

Comment: That will not work around not the solution to my problem

Comment: The frame of a UIView is not guaranteed to be set in "viewDIdLoad".  Try and move that in viewWillLoad.  Does it change?

Comment: i tried to put the log in viewDidLoad for self.view.frame and it prints (0.0 0.0; 1920.0,1080.0). Also now i noticed that when i set  avplayerVC?.view.frame =  CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1920.0, 1079.0) then playback controls are not visible.

Comment: The only think I can think of for inconsistent behaviour is that you did not use addChildViewController and that might cause some odd behaviour in children views.